# Get all the attributes of a DOM Node

Tags: javascript, dom

I needed this small function for one of my project.

[Fetch Attributes](http://jsbin.com/yuyajidaja/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
function fetchAttrs(node) {

  if (!node || !node.hasAttributes()) return {};
  var attrs = node.attributes;
  var res = {};
  var length = attrs.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var attr = attrs[i];
    res[attr.name] = attr.value;
  }
  return res;
}
```

It's working fine as expected but I wanted to know if I am missing something from a performance point of view or good coding practices. Just need a second opinion :)

**Update**

How to handle exceptions, is it a good practice?

Comment: From a safety point of view, you are assuming the passed in `node` has both `.hasAttributes()` and `.attributes` or it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much of a performance difference between the two (reduce is very slightly favoured in my own tests), but I prefer the more readable `reduce` function over the `for` loop. I believe it makes the code simpler, too. Also sort of a personal preference - why not use the full name? No real need in shortening it. :-)

```
var fetchAttributes = function(node) {
  return node && Array.prototype.reduce.call(node.attributes, function(list, attribute) {
    list[attribute.name] = attribute.value;
    return list;
  }, {}) || {};
};
```

http://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-for-fetch-attributes

Edit: In fact you can simplify this further, as you aren't transforming the attributes in any way.

```
var fetchAttributes = function(node) {
    return node && node.attributes || {};
};
```

Comment: Johan, `node.attributes` is an `object`, not an `array`; so we have to borrow the `reduce` method from the `array` `prototype`. If it were, you could simply do `return node && node.attributes.reduce(function(list, attribute) { // ... `. :-)

Comment: Seems a elegant approach. But I have a doubt in mind, reduce will be called for each element and hence will be a overhead as compared to simple attribute access.

Comment: Does it really work? http://jsfiddle.net/55gx9q47/

Comment: Doesn't seem to with a plain object. However the callback function is called when iterating over the `node.attributes` object. See my updated answer for a solution without using `reduce` at all.